# Ejecutar función JAVA en JSP desde un script

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

Me encuentro trabajando con Java Web en Netbeans 8.1, actualmente implementando AJAX en el proyecto y surge la siguiente incidencia:

Este es mi función JS en mi JSP:

```
$("#formAddFundo").submit(function(event) {

 /* stop form from submitting normally */
 event.preventDefault();

 /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
 var $form = $(this),
     url = $form.attr('action');


 var status = 0;

 if (document.getElementById("chkFundo").checked)
     var status = 1;

 /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
 var posting = $.post(url, {
     hIdFundo: $('#hIdFundo').val(),
     txtNombre: $('#txtNombre').val(),
     status: status,
     btnAddGrid: $('#btnAddGrid').val()
 });

 /* Alerts the results */
 posting.done(function(data) {

     $.get('addFundo', function(responseJson) {
         var t = $('#dt_basic').DataTable();
         t.clear();

         $.each(responseJson, function(index, objeto) { // Iterate over the JSON array.
             var estado;

             if (objeto.status === 1) {
                 estado = "Activo";
             } else {
                 estado = "No activo";
             }

             t.row.add([
                 objeto.idfundo,
                 objeto.nombre,
                 estado,
                 "<i class=\"btn btn-secondary fa fa-pencil\" onclick=\"update('" + objeto.nombre + "', '" + objeto.idfundo + "', '" + objeto.status + "');\"></i></a><a><i class=\"btn btn-secondary fa fa-trash-o\" onclick=\"borrar('" + objeto.nombre + "', '" + objeto.idfundo + "');\"></i></a>"
             ]).draw(false);
         });


         $('#alerta').html("<div class='alert alert-warning'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Atención!</strong> " + <%= session.getAttribute("Respuesta") %> +" </strong></div>");
     });

     limpiar();
 });

 });
```

Y este es mi Servlet donde va a buscar la respuesta:

```
 String json = new Gson().toJson(listaFundos);

 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(json);

 request.getSession().setAttribute("Respuesta", resp);
```

La duda ahora es... Se debe dibujar en pantalla el HTML de #alerta en el JSP sin refrescarse al momento de haber terminado el POST del servlet el cual me devolvió el Json ya trabajado. Las variables de session y los scripplets solo se ejecutan al momento de cargan la página, no en ejecuciones posteriores.

```
 $('#alerta').html("<div class='alert alert-warning'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Atención!</strong> " + <%= session.getAttribute("Respuesta") %> +" </strong></div>");
```

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la variable "resp" de tu código Java?

Comment: Un simple String con el comentario que quiero mostrar dentro de un DIV del JSP.

Comment: Favor de indicarnos que información contiene "data", ya que dicho parámetro contiene el resultado de POST generado por tu formulario.

Comment: Devuelve el Json que pueden ver en el segundo bloque de codigo. el Gson().toJson(lista)

Answer (score 1):

Los scriptlets JSP nunca se van a evaluar de nuevo tras la carga de la página, por que es normal que cuando llamas a tu método ajax el alert siempre muestre lo mismo.
Lo que tienes que hacer es modificar la llamada ajax y devolver, por ejemplo, un objeto compuesto por dos propiedades:

- la lista que ya devuelve ahora mismo
- el mensaje a mostrar en el alert

Una vez hecho eso el cambio es fácil.